# local notification not showing up flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to use local notification package, trying to send a notification when the internet connection is lost, internet connection checking is fine, but I'm facing an issue in notification part. the error message is "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference"  my main.dart is https://sourceb.in/4NUViEivKn  (the problem is in 60th line on the setStateI think)   my notification_api.dart https://sourceb.in/oDwdd3CTSg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't initialize the plugin to use it, you can follow their docs it's well explained [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#initialisation)

Comment: Thank you so much, I was following a tutorial, but they didn't initialize the plugin there. I've read the documentation now the problem is gone.